# Finding a way to insert CC: / email address field into MBOX files

Tags: email

I have tons of MBOX email files classified into projects subfolders (on Linux server / filesystem, each sub-folder is a project name).

```
Public
|_Project1
| |_mbox_file_1
| |_mbox_file_2
|
|_Project2
| |_mbox_file_1
| |_mbox_file_2
|
|_Etc
```

I have to check every email header (seems that the header part end with a blank line) and insert the project's email address into the CC field.

If there is no CC: Field, i think i can just insert the CC: field into the first line:
CC: project-xxx@archive.domain.com
[rest of the mbox file]

If CC: Field present, i have to insert it after the last adress.  So, i'd have to detect the CC: line and place project-xxx@archive.com after the existing last email adress.

```
CC: email@domain1.com,
 email2@domain2.com
...
```

Would become:

```
CC: email@domain1.com,
 email2@domain2.com,
 project-xxx@archive.domain.com
...
```

Or it could be (maybe simpler):

```
CC: email@domain1.com,
 project-xxx@archive.domain.com,
 email2@domain2.com
...
```

How would you do that on Linux?  Any idea for good speed?  (there is 1.5 TB of emails!)

Comment: How do you know the project's email address - can it be derived from the folder that the mbox file resides in (such as `_Project1`)? Is the format of a CC line always as shown in your example, e.g. each address is on a separate line? Would it be possible to put all CC addresses on a single line? Tools like `sed` and `awk` should be up to the task. I don't know about speed, but if you have to do it only once, it doesn't really matter as long as it completes before the end of the world?

Comment: Well, i could possibly derive the project name from folder name.  Inspecting MBOX files, i saw that CC field header are as i presented in my example.  Single line would be easier but that's not what i saw.  sed and awk are probably the best tools for that but i have to come up with the right REGEX to do the job, but i'm no REGEX wizard!

Comment: Indeed, email headers may be spread over several lines, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-2.2.3. The easiest solution would be adding the project address at the end of the line that starts with CC. The risk is that the line may become too long, but I think it is very small, since the standard allows roughly 1000 characters. Quick and dirty first approach `for project in Public/*; do sed -i.bak "/^CC:/s/$/, ${project}@archive.domain.com"/ $project/*; done`. This only processes email messages that have a CC line already.

Comment: The `sed` command above only processes lines that start with CC:, replacing the end of line with `, ${project}@archive.domain.com`. The replacement is made in the original mailbox file, and a backup of the original file is made. In spite of this backup, I strongly recommend testing this on a copy of your email folders until you are confident it works. Unfortunately, I don't have a one-line solution for detecting emails that have no CC: header.

Comment: I'll test the result with a linked copy of a folder:  cp -al project-001 project-001-test  so i don't need the BAK file.

Comment: I fear that you will operate on the original file content. If there is anything wrong with my approach, you risk destroying your data.

Comment: @berndbausch No worry, as i said just above, i'll test with a hard-linked copy of a directory structure before launching the real job!  But in your solution, what if the line already has a comma at the end?  (there is already more than 1 CC address)

Comment: Yes, I did not take the comma at the end into account. You could use two `sed` commands, one processing lines that have a comma at the end `sed "/CC:.*, *$/...`, the other processing lines without one `sed "/CC:.*[^,] *$/...`. These two regular expressions also work with lines that have trailing spaces.